# GeoServer CQL Filter IN and strToLowerCase

Tags: geoserver, cql-filter, cql

I am trying to query GeoServer with a CQL Filter using the IN clause.

If I send a request like this I get data back.

http://server.com/geoserver/server/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=server:states&CQL_FILTER=state_name%20in%20(%27Texas%27)&outputFormat=application/json

but if I send a url with strToLowerCase around state_name it will not work.

http://server.com/geoserver/server/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=server:states&CQL_FILTER=strToLowerCase(state_name)%20in%20(%27Texas%27)&outputFormat=application/json

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: You are comparing lower-case state names with **T**exas (capital T), so you can expect to get no result

Comment: Sorry messed up the second url. It should be http://server.com/geoserver/server/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=server:states&CQL_FILTER=strToLowerCase(state_name)%20in%20(%27texas%27)&outputFormat=application/json I reccieved the same error that you noted below in your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the logs, CQL does't accept `IN` after `strToLoweCase`

```
Caused by: org.geotools.filter.text.cql2.CQLException: Encountered "in" at line 1, column 28. Was expecting one of:
    <EOF> 
    "and" ...
    "or" ...
    ";" ...
    "*" ...
    "/" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "not" ...
    "like" ...
    "ilike" ...
    "exists" ...
    "does-not-exist" ...
    "is" ...
    "between" ...
    "=" ...
    ">" ...
    "<" ...
    ">=" ...
    "<=" ...
    "<>" ...
     Parsing : strToLowerCase(STATE_NAME) in ('texas','abc').
```

So you would have to use `=` and `or`

```
 strToLowerCase(STATE_NAME) = 'texas' or strToLowerCase(STATE_NAME) = 'florida'
```